# Laravel cashier swapping taking immediate effect

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

As per the documentation `swap()` method swap the current subscription with the new one on the next billing date, means after end of current plan. And `swapAndInvoice()` will take immediate effect without waiting for the current plan to end.

But the `swap()` method is not working as described. It is taking immediate effect.

```
$subscription_result = $user->subscription('primary')->swap('new_price_id');
```

This is what I am using to swap subscription.

> example

,

```
Plan A :- 3 days ($3)
Plan B :- 7 days ($7)
```

User subscribed to **Plan A** on **25th March**, next billing cycle is on **28th March**.
User changed subscription to **Plan B** on **25th March**, it should take effect on 28th (`using swap() method`). But it is taking effect immediately and showing next billing cycle is on **1st April**.

I have tried using `swapAndInvoice()` instead of `swap()`, but both the methods are giving same output, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is not related to the `swap()` method specifically, but instead to how [Subscription upgrades and downgrades](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing) behave. When you update a subscription to a price with a different interval than the previous price (like with your example a 3 day interval vs. 7 day interval), then the billing_cycle_anchor will be reset immediately and a new invoice will be generated. The `swapAndInvoice()` method will cut a new invoice at the time of the Subscription update regardless of whether the intervals of the price update stay the same. Whereas just using `swap()` in the case where the interval of the two prices are the same would result in an invoice not being created until the next natural billing cycle.

The Stripe API way to accomplish your use-case here would be to utilize [Subscription Schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules). However, Cashier may not support this feature directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood correctly then the `swap()` method will not wait for the current subscription to end if the intervals are not same. In my case the intervals for `3 days` and `7 days` are not same, and hence the `swap()` method is generating the invoice immediately, which I don't want and to accomplish this I need to use `Stripe API` directly which is not supported by `Cashier`. Right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, but might have found a workaround. I'm still testing it myself so bear that in mind.

In short, it's not Cashier that's the issue, Stripe's default behaviour when billing period changes in a subscription is to charge immediately. (If it was the same billing period however, it would charge in the future. Unfortunately not what we need here.)
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#immediate-payment

However, Stripe is designed to handle multiple subscriptions per user! Cashier auth()->user()->subscription() will always pull their most recent subscription so it works nicely.

1. Cancel their existing subscription (stripe will attach a "grace period" until their scheduled expiry date).
2. Get default payment method
3. Create a new subscription (with a trial period of however long was left on the last subscription. You'll need this date saved somewhere).
4. I added 'proration_behavior' => 'none' as $subscriptionOptions (dug in the code to find create() accepts more than one parameter). Unsure if this is what made the difference, but haven't tested yet without it.
5. You will have to manage the actual "expiration date" yourself somewhere, which is fine because you will need this date somewhere for #3 anyways. Just ensure your date updating is accurate.

Code Ex.

```
auth()->user()->subscription('default')->cancel();

$payment_method = auth()->user()->defaultPaymentMethod()->id;

auth()->user()->newSubscription('default',  $plan->stripe_plan_id)
      ->trialDays(45)
      ->create($payment_method, [], ['proration_behavior' => 'none']);

return redirect()->route('billing')->withMessage('Subscription successfully changed');
```

Note: Your "trial_ends_at" date under subscriptions table will be inaccurate. I'm recommend using "trial_ends_at" under users table which isn't tied to payments when a user registers.